# move_uploaded_file()

Tags: php

Buen Día, Estoy trabajando con `Xammp` creando un `API` que carga archivos y tengo este código:

```
$nomarchivo = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$tipoarchivo = $_FILES['file']['type'];
$tamano = $_FILES['file']['size'];
$uploadsdir = "*/files/";

if (($tipoarchivo === "application/pdf") && ($tamano < 1000000)) {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadsdir.$nomarchivo);
} else {
    echo "Solo se permiten archivos pdf y temaño menor a 125kb";
}
```

pero da estos errores:

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(*/files/Test.pdf): failed to open stream:
>   No error in C:\xampp\htdocs\pruebas\api\subearchivo.php on line 12
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move
>   'C:\xampp\tmp\phpD852.tmp' to '*/files/Test.pdf' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\pruebas\api\subearchivo.php on line 12

Probe con el `path` completo para evitar el error pero no funciona. que mas puede ser?

Comment: ¿Estás usando un comodín como nombre para el directorio `$uploadsdir`? ¿Eso es correcto? ¿Existe el directorio `*/files/`?

Answer (score 1):

El problema esta en esta linea:

```
$uploadsdir = "*/files/";
```

Deberia de ir de la siguiente forma:

```
$uploadsdir = "./files/";
```

o

```
$uploadsdir= "files/";
```

Comment: Gracias, al cambiarlo con tu sugerencia me funciono. junto con la función copy.

Answer (score 0):

El `$uploadsdir` no me parece correcto el "resultado" de la ruta `*/files/`; usa ruta relativa o específica.

*También verifica que el usuario bajo el cual corre el servidor web tenga permisos a la carpeta destino (los permisos necesarios).*

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo hago con la funcion copy , no se si te sirva así
 $upload_folder = '../Facturas';

```
        $nombre_archivo = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];

        $tipo_archivo = $_FILES['archivo']['type'];

        $tamano_archivo = $_FILES['archivo']['size'];

        $tmp_archivo = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];

        $archivador = $upload_folder . '/' . $nombre_archivo;

        copy($tmp_archivo, $archivador);
```

Comment: Gracias con la función Copy me funciono, y con el cambio del path que estaba utilizando, gracias a todos